# Converting a list of objects to a list of string without iteration

Tags: apex, soql

I need a comma separated list of Names of a custom object. I tried the below code.

```
List<string> lstNames = new List<string>();
lstNames = [Select Name from A__c where field__c =: objB.Id ];
string Names = string.join(lstNames,',')
```

It gives me an error that Illegal assignment from List to List. I know it is because I am trying to convert a list of A__c to a list of string. Is there a way available to convert a list of object to a list of string without iterating through each record or to get a comma separated list of values without iteration?

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to do this without iteration, whats the problem with that out of interest?

Comment: Recently I have to write code to produce a list of name fields so often. All I need is a list of text fields in objects, so I was wondering if there is a way to convert the list of text fields to a list of strings without iteration so I could avoid the for loop and a few lines of code.

Comment: You are going to need a for loop for this as you require data for each queried record.  A [foreach loop](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm) with the use of an inline query will give you best results for your requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
List<String> lstNames = new List<String>();
for(A__c ac: [Select Name from A__c where field__c =: objB.Id]){
    lstNames.add(ac.Name);
}
String names = string.join(lstNames,',');
System.debug(names);
```

Your code not works because you are trying to assign an object to a string.

-edit
In my opinion, this is not possible without loop.

Comment: This uses for loop. I want to know whether it can be done without for loop.

Answer (score -1):

Do something like this:

```
string s = [select name from A__c where field__c =: objB.Id ].name; //if it returns only 1 record. 
system.debug('s=='+s);
list<string> lstNames = new list<string>();
lstNames.add(s);
string Names = string.join(lstNames,',');
system.debug('Names='+Names);
```

Comment: I assume that the SOQL will return 1 record

Answer (score -1):

Please use below code snippet, it should work fine. Let's assume the object is Account.

```
List<AggregateResult> accList= [select name from Account group by name]; 
String str = JSON.serialize(accList);
str = str.removeStart('[{"attributes":{"type":"AggregateResult"},"Name":"');
str= str.replace('"},{"attributes":{"type":"AggregateResult"},"Name":"',',');
Str= str.removeEnd('"}]');

system.debug('Names='+str);
```

Comment: @saranya : does this help?

Comment: I feel quite confident that JSON serialization is going to be significantly less efficient than the for loop.